# Not able to login if browsers cookies are disable

Tags: php, cookies, browser, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe PHP framework, in which I have some login panels. My issue is when I disable cookies in my browser, I'm not able to log in. Can I escape cookies when I log in? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: The cookie is how your server identifies you and is able to provide functions like logging in. Why would you want to disable them ?

Comment: @JohannduToit users are funny like that...

Comment: actually i m not disabling it, my clients those are using my application are disabling the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be not using cookie at all and instead turning the

```
session.use_only_cookies to "0"
```

forcing to append session id to urls. This has a potential drawbacks some one getting the url can hack in to others session. Also any change in the state will be appended to url.